# UPDATE field value if contains at least this text

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the correct SQL query to UPDATE fields from a table that contain at least some text. My idea is something like this.

```
UPDATE this IN tablename WHERE fieldname = "%value%"
```

I know something is wrong but I am new to this and in need of some help. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using an `INSERT` query if you want to perform an `UPDATE`? And what do you mean by `some text`? Is that a non empty string? Matching a substring value? Please clarify.

Comment: `INSERT` is to insert a row into table.  `UPDATE` is to update existing row in the table.  The first question is do you want to insert or update???

Comment: @Eric UPDATE, my bad. thanks

Comment: @fubar some text means the text that if inside the value I want to select to then update with a new text. in this case if the value contains "%@bd.com%" then replace with email "bd1234@gmail.com"

Comment: Have you Google the `UPDATE` syntax???  There are probably millions of example on the web.  I should search there first before posting this silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INSERT statement will add new row(s) into your table.

The UPDATE statement will edit your current row(s).

*You should at least shout if you want some help.*

Please post something more for your question, like table name, column names and your exact requirement.

UPDATE statement is something like this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET field1 = 'TEST' WHERE fieldname LIKE "%value%";
```

Comment: sorry, so if field1 and fieldname are the same column. How would you do it? field name is 'email' and tablename is 'wpfe_users' and want to replace all emails that have "@bd.com" in them.

Comment: `UPDATE tablename SET email = ‘bd1234@gmail.com’ WHERE email LIKE ‘%@bd.com’;`

Comment: @Joekom Ok! Then the query should be `UPDATE tablename SET field1 = 'TEST' WHERE field1 LIKE "%value%";` But, please do create a backup of your table then test the query and confirm that the query is working according to your expectations. Because I once tried to do something like `UPDATE ledger SET credit=debit, debit=credit;` and the result was same as `UPDATE ledger SET credit=debit;` , OK? got it?